# How do I retrieve specific attributes of a relationship/collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, collections, relationship

Is there a good way to retrieve all of a specific attribute from a relationship/collection?  For instance, I want a list of all the names of a person's cars.  Obviously I can't do the following:

Person.Cars.Name(s)

...but does something of that nature exist in ruby (or is there an ActiveRecord helper method) that handles that?  Obviously I could iterate over all the cars and append to an array, but I'd like something a bit cleaner.  Any ideas?

Best.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `cars` is an association of a `person`, and `name` a property of a `car`, then you can do the following:

```
# person = Person.find(conditions)
person.cars.collect { |car| car.name }
```

Or even (thanks to `ActiveSupport` and/or Ruby 1.9):

```
person.cars.collect(&:name)
```

*Update:* this is documented in the following places:

- [Association proxy for `has_many` returns `Array`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M002123)
- [`Array#collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002187)
- [`Symbol#to_proc` in `ActiveSupport`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Symbol.html#M000007), used in the second example
- [`Symbol#to_proc` in Ruby 1.9](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Symbol.html#M000031)

*Update 2:* an example that applies formatting:

```
person.cars.collect { |car| "(#{car.name})" }
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.  Where exactly is that documented? I must admit, I have quite a time with Ruby/Rails when it comes to intuiting where to find certain functionality.  Even using online documentation I'm not really able to find some of the cooler items of this nature.

Comment: The &:name syntax is built into Ruby 1.9 as well, so you can use it outside of Rails apps if you're targeting newer Ruby versions.

Comment: The reason you don't see this in the Rails docs is that Enumerable#collect (or its synonym #map) are just part of plain old Ruby.

Comment: Is there any way to manipulate the returned data?  For instance, I want to place brackets around each returned word for formatting purposes.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Ok, basically I'm building a DB query.  So I need it in the form of joined quoted strings.  I have:



    points.collect(&:name).join(",")



Any way to work with that?  And thanks for those last few posts, btw.

Comment: @humble_coder, sure, you can just append .join(", ") to join the array into a single string. Even the formatted array with parenthesis. But this is starting to sound scary. You probably do not have to build a DB query yourself if you use ActiveRecord. It created specifically to handle this abstraction for you. Perhaps post a separate question to get some info how to deal with it in your specific case?

Comment: Actually, the situation is a bit convoluted.  I'm using Gruff to plot points for a table of various Points.  The whole Person/Car thing was completely contrived.  Basically I have several METERS that have associated POINTS and VALUES and I'm charting them.  So for each point associated with a meter, I need to grab those values from the "values" table and plot them for that day.  That being the case, I need to loop through and dynamically acquire each point/value combo for any meter at any given time.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: @humble_coder, sort of. Does the example that adds parentheses, together with a trailing join() help you out?.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely helps.  I ended up using this code:



    ...points = self.points.collect{|p| "\'#{p.name}\'"}.join(",")...


That gave me a series of single-quoted strings for placing in the query.  I'm looking to do a single query, hence the join.  What I need now, however, is to loop through all groups of points in the resulting query independently.  Are there any cool "collect" tricks (or otherwise) for acquiring values of a specific type in an existing result set?

Comment: @humble_coder, you may want to look at Array#select: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002191 ?

Answer (score 0):

In newer rails versions (> 3.2.1), you can use the method `pluck`, whitch is a method from `ActiveRecord`, so it does retrieve the attributes way faster than any order array method (`map`, `collect` etc.).

I this case, you can use like this:
`Person.pluck(:name)`

But as a `ActiveRecord` method, you can only use it in `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not in arrays